# Can not deserialize instance of parseJason when using Jackson to parse the Json File

Tags: java, json, parsing, jackson, mapper

I have a Json file :

```
[
{
      "name":"Move",
      "$$hashKey":"object:79",
      "time":11.32818,
      "endTime":18.615535
   },
   {
      "name":"First Red Flash",
      "$$hashKey":"object:77",
      "time":15.749153
   },
   {
      "name":"Pills",
      "subEventTypes":[
         "pull down bottle",
         "unscrew lid",
         "dump pills out",
         "screw lid on",
         "put bottle away"
      ],
      "$$hashKey":"object:82",
      "time":25.130175,
      "subEventSplits":[
         26.092057,
         27.425881,
         31.841594,
         34.268093
      ],
      "endTime":36.234827
   }


]
```

I tried to parse this Json file using the Jackson. 
I wrote the following code:

```
public class Holder{
        public Holder(){};
        //getter and setters

        String name;
        List<String> subEventTypes = new ArrayList<>();
        Double time;
        String $$hashKey;
        Double endTime;
        List<Double> subEventSplits = new ArrayList<>();

    }
class MapperClass{
    List<Holder> list = new ArrayList<>();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException, IOException
{
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    List<Holder>  list = mapper.readValue(new File("data.json"), mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(
            List.class, Holder.class));

}
```

When I run the program, it showed this error : "

```
No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class parseJason$Holder]: can not instantiate from JSON object (need to add/enable type information?)
```

".
Is there anything wrong with my code? or I have to use another way to parse my Json file.

Comment: always check with jsonlint.com as to whether this is valid json or not

Comment: **After** your edit it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
list = mapper.readValue(
                jsonString,
                objectMapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(
                        List.class, Holder.class));
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I got the following error "No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class parseJason$Holder]: can not instantiate from JSON object (need to add/enable type information?)
 at [Source: data.json; line: 3, column: 7]"

Comment: Yep, you will need a default constructor plus getter/setters in your `Holder`

Comment: I figured it out. I have to add "static" for the inner class "holder"